# On tap close button image its not closing in first tap in iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone

I am trying to close the page in first tap in iPhone but its closing on second tap. On tap its image changes but is not closing.

```js
$("#privacy-close-btn").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#privacy-close-btn").css("display", "none");
  $("#privacy-close-btn-act").css("display", "block");
});
$("#privacy-close-btn-act").mouseout(function() {
  $("#privacy-close-btn").css("display", "block");
  $("#privacy-close-btn-act").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
a img.privacy-close-btn-act {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="close-img">
  <img src="assets/img/desktop_privacy_close_inactive.svg" alt="" class="privacy-close-btn" id="privacy-close-btn">
  <img src="assets/img/desktop_privacy_close_active.svg" alt="" class="privacy-close-btn-act" id="privacy-close-btn-act">
</a>
```

Comment: why are you using `mouseenter` and `mouseout`? they will not function the same way they do on Desktop.

Comment: How are you expecting the mouse events to work on a touch device?

Comment: You should consider using touch events if you are going to target touch devices. Here is some info https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 0):

mouseenter and mouseover are "parts" of hover, as hover is a click (to trigger hover event) on touchscreen devices it seems rationnal it would work the same for mouseenter and mouseover.

If you wanna use a click just use onclick or similar click feature.